# Phonetic search or matching in Solr is not working

Tags: xml, linux, solr

I have to configure Solr for phonetic matching. e.g if the telephone is some value in the indexed document then for a query like 'telepfone' should show telephone in the result. Please find below the managed-schema.XML file in which I have done the changes. So Now after doing all the configuration in this xam file I restarted the solr and reindexed the docs. After that when I query for telephone it returns nothing in the result. It is only working for the exact match and not for the phonetic match.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Solr managed schema - automatically generated - DO NOT EDIT -->
<schema name="example-data-driven-schema" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <fieldType name="ancestor_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" currencyConfig="currency.xml" defaultCurrency="USD" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="dates" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="delimited_payloads_float" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="delimited_payloads_int" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="integer"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="delimited_payloads_string" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="identity"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="descendent_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="doubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="floats" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="ignored" class="solr.StrField" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="false" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="ints" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" geo="true" maxDistErr="0.001" distErrPct="0.025" distanceUnits="kilometers"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="longs" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pdates" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pdoubles" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pfloats" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="phonetic_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">         
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000"  />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="0" 
        generateWordParts="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateNumberParts="0"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">     
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="0" 
        generateWordParts="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateNumberParts="0"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>        
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

  <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="pints" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="plongs" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" subFieldSuffix="_d" dimension="2"/>
  <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
  <fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="6"/>
  <fieldType name="tdates" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="6"/>
  <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tdoubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_bg" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_bg.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.BulgarianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ca" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_ca.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ca.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Catalan"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_cjk" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_cz" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_cz.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.CzechStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_da" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_da.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Danish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_el" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.BeiderMorseFilterFactory" nameType="GENERIC" ruleType="APPROX" concat="true" languageSet="auto"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="false" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="false" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  ...
  <fieldType name="text_ga" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_ga.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/hyphenations_ga.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.IrishLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ga.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Irish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33" maxPosAsterisk="3" withOriginal="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_gl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_gl.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GalicianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  ...
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tfloats" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tints" class="solr.TrieIntField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <fieldType name="tlongs" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" multiValued="true" precisionStep="8"/>
  <field name="-213.25" type="tdoubles"/>
  <field name="0.8" type="tdoubles"/>
  <field name="3" type="tlongs"/>
  <field name="35" type="tdoubles"/>
  <field name="38.94" type="tdoubles"/>
  <field name="Description" type="strings"/>
  <field name="Eldon_Base_for_stackable_storage_shelf__platinum" type="strings"/>
  <field name="Muhammed_MacIntyre" type="strings"/>
  <field name="Name" type="strings"/>
  ...
  <field name="extended_properties_application" type="strings"/>
  <field name="extended_properties_appversion" type="tdoubles"/>
  <field name="features" type="strings"/>
  <field name="foo" type="tdoubles"/>
  <field name="foo1" type="tlongs"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  ...
  <field name="xmptpg_npages" type="tlongs"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en_split_tight" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_descendent_path" type="descendent_path" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ancestor_path" type="ancestor_path" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en_split" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_rev" type="text_general_rev" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_phon_en" type="phonetic_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_s_lower" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_cjk" type="text_cjk" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  ...
  <copyField source="*" dest="_text_"/>
</schema>
```

Comment: Which field are you searching? What does the "analysis" page under Solr admin show for your indexed string and your query string? Those field names as numbers doesn't really seem correct either..

Comment: Not searching for particular field. My query is like q='telephone' which returns in response "response":{"numFound":204,"start":0,"maxScore":7.038185,"docs":[ ..... but when I do q='telefone'  , i get the repsonse like this :
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
  }}

Comment: Everything is searching against a field - if you don't have a field defined in your actual query, Solr uses the default search field from the schema, or the field defined in `df` (for the standard query parser) or in `qf` (for dismax and edismax).

Comment: Please read my question at first place and answer to that question. Whatever you said I already know that and that is not the solution for the problem I am facing.

Comment: Sorry, but _how_ a match is produced in solr depends on _which_ field definition you're using. If you don't get a match, that will depend on the definition for _that field type_. If you don't search against a field type defined as phonetic, explicitly, it won't help. Unless you're able to provide the field type for the _field you're searching against_, saying anything useful about why you're not getting a hit won't be possible. This is also important for you to know how the text for that field is processed, and to further debug the issue under the "Analysis" page in the Admin interface.

Comment: Filed type for the field is text_en. there is field name "Nunavut", for this field when I query with q=Nunavut:Ontario then it returns all the exact matching records. but when I query it with q=Nunavut:Onterio it returns nothing. Now the field type for this field is text_en. And Now for the analysis I entered 'Ontario' in the 'Field Value(Index)' box and selected 'text_en' from 'Analyse Fieldname/FieldType' and then I clicked on Analyse Values button. I couldn't understand whatever appears in the output.

Comment: There is nothing in your field type for the `text_en` field type that indicate that it should convert anything to a phonetic representation when indexing the content; you have a BeiderMorse filter when _querying_, but if you're not doing it on both sides, it won't work (since the generated tokens will be different). If you have questions about the analysis page, include a screenshot of the values it output.